# body.dir="auto" throws exception on IE/Edge - set when setting directionality="auto" in tinyMCE

Tags: right-to-left, tinymce-4, bidi

FYI to you all,
This is also a tinyMCE bug (that should ignore this setting in IE/Edge to prevent the exception)
In IE/Edge run the following at the console:

```
document.querySelector("body").dir="rtl"; //"rtl"
document.querySelector("body").dir="ltr"; //"ltr"
document.querySelector("body").dir="auto"; //Invalid argument.
```

you get this error when passing the setting directionality="auto" in tinyMCE (it should ignore it..)
The error you see at the console is Invalid argument  at N.prototype.initContentBody ... at the tinyMCE source

Comment: "solution" - check for IE/Edge and don't set directionality="auto" [best described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser/9851769#9851769)